# Why isn't loadposition working to load a module within a custom HTML module in Joomla 3.2?

Tags: joomla, module

I am developing a website with Joomla 3.2. I want to put a search box inside a custom HTML module. I have the module loading plugin enabled, a module position defined for the search box ('searchbox'), created the module instance, assigned it to the correct position, enabled it, and made sure it was assigned to all pages.

Inside my custom HTML module I inserted the following:

```
{loadposition searchbox}
```

As you can see here - http://ojospa.webez.net/ - it isn't working (look in the upper right hand corner).

Why isn't it working? I've looked over everything to make sure there were no typos and everything looks fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Cynthia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable the "Prepare Content" parameter in the options of the module. Then it should work.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks :) See what I get for working mostly on WP development for the last year and a half? I forget everything I ever knew about Joomla.